# gradle uploadArchives exclude java package

Tags: java, maven, gradle, upload, build.gradle

I want to exclude some java packages when uploading project. But all i find is to remove package from jar file. There is no example of removing package when upload process. Is there anyone know how to exlude java packages or web resources when uploading project with gradle ?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to exclude the packages? Maybe there's another way to solve your problem.

Comment: I use a package in project1 and i want to use it in project2 as an interface to that project to use some functionalities. Also i don't want to seperate the package to another project. Gradle can exclude from jar but i couldn't find a way to exclude when uploadArchives execution.

Comment: Gradle has great support for multi-project builds. You might be better off splitting your JAR into two projects, one API JAR with your interfaces, and one JAR with the implementation.

Comment: I think your approach is better thanks @dnault